# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'opTuple' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7

the following code give the error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'opTuple' referenced before assignment".(it's a minimal code)

```
def opHandler(op):

    if op.type == 2 :
        opTuple = ("push_contact", op.param1, op.param2)
    elif op.type == 5 :
        opTuple = ("add_contact", op.param1, op.param2, op.param3)
    elif op.type == 8 :
        opTuple = ("recommed_contact", op.param1)

    return opTuple

while True :
    op1 = getOp(114514); # returns the op object

    opArray = opHandler(op1)

    print opArray
```

I think the variable "opTuple" is a local variable and that's what I wish, and I haven't used the same name before neither in this code nor in the library.

How can I fix this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is op.type always one of 2, 5 or 8?

Comment: What happens when you pass in something other than 2, 5, or 8? You should give opTuple a default value.

Comment: Yaah agree with @DSM, we don't know what op.type is you should put print statements and please feed tracebook.

Comment: yeah, op.type has other number than 2, 5 and 8 and I have just give opTuple a default value and it 's solved !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a default value to `opTuple` if the values passed in don't match your conditional checks:

```
def op_handler(op):

    op_tuple = (None, None, None) # default value

    if op.type == 2 :
        op_tuple = ("push_contact", op.param1, op.param2)
    elif op.type == 5 :
        op_tuple = ("add_contact", op.param1, op.param2, op.param3)
    elif op.type == 8 :
        op_tuple = ("recommed_contact", op.param1)

    return op_tuple
```